# Is there a way to fetch files inside a matlab uihtml component?

Tags: html, matlab, matlab-app-designer

I am using a `uihtml` component inside a `uifigure` that loads a HTML file in its HTMLSource property. The HTML file just tries to fetch the contents of a text file located in the same folder, and outputs them inside a `div` component. The body in the HTML looks something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
    
    <script>
        fetch("./example.txt")
            .then(response => response.text) 
            .then(textString => {
                document.getElementById('viewer').innerHTML = textString;
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

The problem is that I always get a "Page Not Found" (the status from the fetch response is 404). The documentation of `uihtml` says: *Common web file types, like JavaScript and CSS, can be referenced from the HTML file you specify for the HTMLSource property, but other web file types might not be supported.*, so I am not sure if it is even possible to fetch a text/pdf/any other file.

From what I understand, when calling `uihtml` MATLAB injects an `iframe` on the webpage displayed by the uifigure. This iframe runs on a local web server, and whenever you append a `script` tag with a source, the `script` is also accessed from the web server. For example,

```
<body>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
    <script id="script-id" src = "./example.js"></script>
    <script>
         document.getElementById("viewer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("script-id").src;
    </script>
</body>
```

would display the source of the js file, which corresponds to something like:
https://localhost:31515/static/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/example.js

That same location of the file we could get by appending the undocumented

1. `connector.getBaseUrl`
2. `matlab.ui.internal.URLUtils.parseURL('/example.js',0)`

I have tried fetching the text file with the full path to that web server location
(https://localhost:31515/static/.../example.txt)
but the 404 error persists.

At this level of HTML/JS is where I start to struggle. It looks like there should be some way to fetch the data of the file since scripts can be loaded, but I can't find a way. Does anybody know how to successfully fetch the file? Do we need a special credential in the fetch request or something like that?